# How to properly pass parameters between modelView and View for the datacontext

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I have the following:
- class AccountViewModel : BaseViewModel
- AccountView.xaml

I'm struggling to pass parameters to the ModelView.

in the main window, I bind them together:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AccountViewModel}">
     <local:AccountView />
</DataTemplate>
```

In the mainWindowViewModel, I have an action to display the Account view by doing:

```
ChangeViewModel(new AccountViewModel(new DateTime(2016, 2, 06), new DateTime(2016, 2, 15)))
```

As you can see, the AccountViewModel takes 2 arguments for its constructor, 2 Datetime.

Then in the AccountView, I try to create a DataContext by doing:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="local:AccountViewModel"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <sys:DateTime></sys:DateTime>
            <sys:DateTime></sys:DateTime>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Whatever I do, it will create another instance of AccountViewModel. I don't want that, I want this AccountView to keep using the AccountViewModel I created in the command shown above but I also want to use the binding functionality. I would rather try to avoid using the code behind if possible.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create an extra object on your `ViewModel`. When your `View` is Defined by your `DataTemplate` `DataType`. It will automatically passed to your View.

[See this answer to understand `DataContext` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367868/datacontext-binding/35369549#35369549)

Remove your below code from your `View` and check the `DataContext`, it will be `local:AccountViewModel`:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="local:AccountViewModel"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        <sys:DateTime></sys:DateTime>
        <sys:DateTime></sys:DateTime>
    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Comment: I actually wasted hours for something that didn't need fixing... Thanks a lot!